# The Formal Parameter @QueryComplete was not declared as output. What might be the problem. The entire stored procedure is attached. Thanks

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have built the following stored procedure. It seems to be working fine and the data is going into the table. However, the Programmable Logic Controller is not able to pick the @QueryComplete value to be 1. What might be the issue here. The only error warning is as follows:

**The Formal Parameter @QueryComplete was not declared as output.**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER       PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Genealogy_WIP]


-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@engine_number      as nvarchar(50),
@line_id            as int,
@stage_id           as int, 
@activity_id        as int,
@activity_value     as nvarchar(50),
@quantity           as int, 
@status             as int,
@plc_YYYY           as int,
@plc_MM             as int,
@plc_DD             as int,
@plc_HR             as int,
@plc_MIN            as int,
@plc_SEC            as int,

-- [Sending Output]
@QueryComplete     int OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from;
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
--SET NOCOUNT ON;
Declare @plc_timestamp nvarchar(20);
SET @plc_timestamp = cast(@plc_YYYY as nvarchar(4)) + '-' +  Cast(@plc_MM as nvarchar(2)) + '-' + Cast(@plc_DD as nvarchar(2)) + ' ' + Cast(@plc_HR as nvarchar(2)) + ':' + Cast(@plc_MIN as nvarchar(2))    + ':' + Cast(@plc_SEC as nvarchar(2));
SELECT @plc_timestamp as 'PLC TIMESTAMP';
    -- Building the Create Statement
            BEGIN TRY
                INSERT INTO [dbo].[Genealogy_WIP]  (
                      [engine_number]
                      ,[line_id]
                      ,[stage_id]
                      ,[activity_id]
                      ,[activity_value]
                      ,[quantity]
                      ,[status]
                      ,[plc_timestamp]
                ) VALUES (
                        @engine_number,
                        @line_id,
                        @stage_id,
                        @activity_id,
                        @activity_value,
                        @quantity,
                        @status,
                        CAST(@plc_timestamp as datetime)
                );
                SET @QueryComplete = 1;
                SELECT @QueryComplete OUTPUT;
                SELECT ' Inserted successfully.' AS Response;
                
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                -- statement to handle errors
                IF  ERROR_NUMBER()=2627
                SELECT '[Error]-You cannot insert this value into the table as there is a primary key violation (in the Line ID field) or one of the inputs is incorrect.' AS Response
            END CATCH
END
```

Comment: FYI the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: Why `SELECT` and also `OUTPUT` the value of `@QueryComplete`? Though, in truth, it looks like you are using `@QueryComplete` to denote success; that is actually what `RETURN` is meant for: `0` for success, and anything else for failure.

Comment: You'll need to post the client code, not the stored procedure.

Comment: Also, in your `CATCH`, you dispose of any errors that aren't `2627`; that seems flawed. Why are you not `THROW`ing an error to the calling application?

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72185778/edit) your question to show the code that's trying to execute the stored procedure. Possibly that's using positional parameters and has them in the wrong order.

Comment: Resultsets are not intended to "send" pretty messages to the calling code. Don't do that.  Remove all those extra resultsets that you included for debugging / development purposes. Those should not be in production code. And your error handling is simply broken. Don't try to catch anything - just let the exception rise to the caller.

Answer (score -1):

When you have to OUTPUT a value from a parameter you must

1. specify the parameter with the keyword OUTPUT in the parameter list (you have done it)
2. set a value to any OUTPUT parameter with SET or SELECT and nothing else (your line "SELECT @QueryComplete OUTPUT;" is wrong. Just write SELECT @QueryComplete = ???" where ??? is a value;

To execute a procedure with a parameter in OUTPUT you must :

1. Declare a variabale that will accept the returned value
2. Write the exec command and specify OUTPUT for the returned value
3. Read the returned value

Example :

DDL :

```
CREATE PROC P @DT DATETIME2 OUTPUT
AS
SET @DT = SYSUTCDATETIME();
GO
```

EXEC :

```
DECLARE @DATETIME2_READ DATETIME2;
EXEC P @DATETIME2_READ OUTPUT;
SELECT @DATETIME2_READ;
```

Comment: But the problem lies within the calling application - this is a purely tsql approach that won't actually fix anything for OP. In addition, you used datetime2 rather than datetime (which is what OP is using based on the code). Don't add confusion. While technically correct for tsql - this does not address OP's multiple issues.

Comment: It does not say anything about application code and set no tag about this topic... Just SQL, SQL Server, Stored Procedure...